# What is the point value of each chess piece?

Tags: point-value

I would like to know the point values of each chess piece. I forgot the values because I have not used that system in quite a long time.

Answer (score 3):

General consensus values chess pieces as follows:

- Pawn = 1 point
- Knight = 3 points
- Bishop = 3 points
- Rook = 5 points
- Queen = 9 points

However, you should consider this valuation scheme (as well as any valuation scheme) to be very vague, to the point where it is almost sloppy to assume it is correct in any specific position. For instance, two bishops together are often valued higher than 3+3, sometimes 6.5 or 7. Or a passed and advanced pawn may easily be worth a piece, especially when connected with another pawn. Rooks, bishops, and queens are worth less than normal when the position is closed, whereas knights thrive in such positions. When the position has clear lanes for the long-range pieces, the knight is less outstanding.

Of interest, too, is the valuation of the king's tactical strength. The king is generally valued between 3 and 4 points, slightly higher than a knight or bishop. Of course, this valuation is meaningless when it comes to calculating exchanges.

[Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_piece_relative_value) on this topic is well-referenced and extensive. There is a table listing various valuation schemes, both historical and modern, and an average of all schemes in the table is given as follows:

- Pawn = 1 point
- Knight = 3.2 points
- Bishop = 3.3 points
- Rook = 5.2 points
- Queen = 9.6 points
- King = 3.5 points